# Part all private messages in weechat

Tags: weechat

I suddenly got spam messages from 600 different "people". Is there a way to close all private messages without closing the application?

All of the messages are from the `mozilla` network, and my messages looks like:

`buffer_autoclose: Closing buffer: mozilla.HeAeeuK
... and 600 more`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same spam, and wanted the same solution.

I solved it by closing the entire Mozilla network. This disconnected me from all Mozilla channels but left other networks unaffected, and that was the important part for me.

You can do this by navigating to the Mozilla network buffer (alt-1, then ctrl-x until you get mozilla) and executing "/close".

Comment: Not ideal, but works ok. Thanks.